# Setting C# 6.0 rules in SonarQube 5.1

Tags: asp.net, sonarqube, sonar-runner, c#-6.0, sonarqube5.1

I installed SonarQube version 5.1 and running it against C# code. The results of the analysis were quite OK, but i was expecting that Sonar would point out the issues based on the latest C# 6.0( which is current now) features too, which seems missing.

Can anyone let me know if i can add new C#6.0 features in some sort of plugin? I am not sure if i can add custom rules for C#, as i couldn't find in their website for c#( found here- http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Writing+Custom+Rules+using+Java)

Comment: What is the version of the C# plugin you use? Did you check if the buildserver contains all the needed .Net Frameworks and the correct MS Build version?

Comment: What kind of C# 6 related rules are you missing?

Answer (score 1):

We are starting to support custom rules for C# with the [SonarQube Roslyn SDK](https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonarqube-roslyn-sdk), which let's you package your custom Roslyn analyzer Nuget package as a SonarQube plugin.

Comment: Thanks @Tamas, Currently i use - MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.0 and sonarqube-5.1. 
Do you have detailed steps how can i analyse using Roslyn sdk? beacuse i could'nt find any

Comment: On the main github page there's a getting started guide. We are planning to do some more announcements/communication on this product in the upcoming weeks, when the connected experience of SonarLint is released.