# Configuring SonarQube to recognise C# 6.0 syntax

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner, c#-6.0, string-interpolation

I am setting up our TeamCity build to run a SonarQube analysis of our C# solution. I have already been through one hurdle by using `-Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8` to allow Sonar to recognise the utf-8 BOM header in our files. My current problem has to do with C# 6.0 syntax, like string interpolation, which does not seem to be recognised by Sonar and is giving me "parse errors":

```
[09:38:39][Step 4/6] 04:38:39.338 ERROR - Unable to parse file: C:\BuildAgent\work\.........\DataLayerTests.cs
[09:38:39][Step 4/6] 04:38:39.338 ERROR - Parse error at line 44 column 46:
[09:38:39][Step 4/6] 
[09:38:39][Step 4/6]    43:             Assert.IsNotNull(results, "The method returned NULL instead of any results.");
[09:38:39][Step 4/6]   -->              Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Count, $"The method returned {results.Count} results instead of 1.");
```

Is there any additional command line parameter that I need to use with the `sonar-runner` to ensure compatibility? Or does this have to do with the version of the C# plugin that we use?

I found this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901273/setting-c-sharp-6-0-rules-in-sonarqube-5-1) question, which is only tangentially related. That question is about enabling the issues that are spotted by the Roslyn analyser to flow back into SonarQube. My question is a lot more basic than that, as I am not yet even at a stage where Sonar would fully understand my syntax!

Comment: Which version of the C# plugin are you using? Why are you dealing directly with `sonar-runner`? Why aren't you using the [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild)?

Comment: We are using SonarQube 4.5.6 with version 3.2 of the C# plugin. We are invoking the SonarQube Runner through a build step in TeamCity, hence my reference to `sonar-runner` (TeamCity calls it automatically).

Comment: I see. That's a very old C# plugin (pre-Roslyn). Upgrading to the latest (or 3.4+) version would solve the C# 6 problems. Check out the versions here: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:versions-panel

Comment: Perfect, thank you Tamas! If you want to write this up as an answer, below, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# plugin has been rewritten in version 3.4 to use Roslyn internally. So any later version will handle (parse) C# 6 features. Also, I recommend to update to the latest version as we are constantly adding new rules, and fixing known issues.

You can check the version history [here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:versions-panel).